# How to delete obsolete translations in gettext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, gettext

i use gettext for a rails project and every time i start my server i get messages like

```
Warning: obsolete msgid exists.
     #~ "some tranlation: "
Warning: obsolete msgid exists.
     #~ "some tranlation: "
...
...
```

Now i know these are just translations that arent used anymore. I would like to delete them but instead of modifying all the .po files i would like to do it with a command.

Is there an easy way to quickly get rid of those translations?

Gems used:

```
 gem 'gettext', '>=1.9.3', :require => false
 gem 'gettext_i18n_rails'
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but check out fast_gettext as a substitute for gettext.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this? I'm currently wondering the same thing..

Comment: No, I still have the same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gettext utilities include a command to do exactly this

```
msgattrib --output-file=xxx.po --no-obsolete xxx.po
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and I used [PoEdit](http://www.poedit.net/) to delete them.

Go in `Catalog>Purge deleted translations`. Then you can run `rake gettext:pack` again and the messages should go.

Note: by default, poedit will create a .mo file sitting next to the .po file. You may want to turn off the option in the settings or just delete the .mo manually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it without deleting them, but here's how to automate the deletion with a shell command:

```
find -name \*.po | xargs sed -i.bak -e '/^#~/d'
```